# React-Native for Mobile

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, react-native-flatlist, gradlew

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI wit
h --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[Fatal Error] gradle-3.1.4.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

When i built this project, then this errors show. I have try to write ./gradlew clean and added some syntax into gradle.properties and also into gradle-wrapper.properties.
Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command

```
react-native doctor
```

and then if its showning some error , press f to fix the issues